# Using "Some" with Singular Countable Nouns

Tags: singular-vs-plural, countable-nouns

we can say " Some idiot driver crashed into the back of me."

but why we can not say " If you’re looking for some book to read, I can recommend ‘Animal Farm’."

we say "a book," the question is why we use some with countable singular nouns somethimes , and sometimes , we do not use it with singular countable nouns ?

Comment: [why can't we say]

Answer (score 6):

In your example sentences, *some* is being used as a determiner to:

> refer to a particular person or thing without stating exactly which one - [Cambridge Dictionary definition C1](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/some)

More than this, it is usually used when the identity of the person or thing is *unknown*, or if it is known and the speaker deliberately wants to be vague, but there is a specific person or thing they are referring to. It is only really used like this in an informal context, or in speech. I wouldn't say that its usage is limited to certain words, more to certain contexts.

In the first example, it is not just *any* "idiot driver", it is a specific "idiot driver", but one who is unknown to the speaker.

In your second example sentence, they are looking for *any* book to read, not a specific, unknown book, so "a" would be more appropriate. I wouldn't say that using "some" book is *wrong*, but it either makes it sound like you've missed off the a plural "s" (some books), or perhaps that you are criticising them for looking for a book to read.

You could, for example, say, when asked what you're reading, *"I'm just reading some book."* (I can't remember/it doesn't matter what I'm reading) or *"I'm reading some Harry Potter book."* (there are a few Harry Potter books, I'm reading one of them, I can't remember/it doesn't matter which one).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I'd agree with OP that we can't say *If you’re looking for some book to read...* But I will admit that in most contexts it would more likely be *If you're **just** looking for some book to read...*

Other answers focusing on the *literal* distinction based on *a **specific** [but unknown] driver* are missing the point of this idiomatic usage. In practice, for contexts like OP's above, you'll very often see either the word ***just*** (as in Q:*Who told you that?* A:*Just some guy in the pub*), and/or a pejorative adjective (as in Q:*Who runs [Elbonia](http://dilbert.wikia.com/wiki/Elbonia)?* A:*Some tinpot dictator*).

In essence, this (primarily *spoken, colloquial*) use of ***some*** X implies a randomly-selected instance of X, *whose precise identity is of no consequence* (all that matters is that it / he ***is*** an X, which is "bad").

---

Thus the implication of *looking for **some** book to read* is that in the speaker's opinion the addressee isn't interested in the finer points of literature - just about any book would do, even if it's poor quality.

Answer (score 0):

*A driver crashed into me* - Articles are more of a signal to the reader/listener than anything for the writer/speaker.  Whoever is saying this merely expects you not to know which driver he/she is talking about.  The writer/speaker may or may not know, but probably does (otherwise they'd use *some*).

*Some driver crashed into me* - This means even the writer/speaker doesn't know which driver actually crashed into him/her.

Answer (score 0):

"He is in some sort of trouble", "There is some reason to support this"“She won’t be here for dinner. She’s spending time with some friend of hers.”

So yes, *some* is sometimes used with singular count nouns.

It has a quite different implication than when “some” is used as a plural indefinite article (where it doesn’t imply anything.)

It often suggests some unknown person, some undefined trouble, some not so-clear reason.

If I said, *She’s not joining us. She met some guy that she’s spending all her time with.* it has a very negative connotation. The other two cases not so much negative as vague or unknown.

My daughter points out that “some” can also be used as a kind of superlative, as in *Charlotte’s Web*: *“Some pig!”* *That’s some car he’s driving!* But it can also imply sarcasm: *Wow, that’s some dress she’s wearing.* (meaning, it’s so bad I don’t even know where to begin.)

I think "unspecified" is the thought that connects all these uses. Other examples or explanations welcomed! (Based on a question asked on Quora)